# The operands for operator 'Equal' do not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality' when running a unit test with just mock

Tags: c#, linq, justmock

We are currently running this expression

```
return x => x.ObjectType != null && x.ObjectType == "SERVICE"
                        && x.Service.Id == searchValue;
```

Which works fine until we come to do a unit test with just mock and it fails with the following exception:

> The operands for operator 'Equal' do not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'

The part of the expression that fails is the null check.  If I replace the expression with just the null check and do the following it fails:

```
_unitOfWork.Repository<Widgits, int>().FindAll(x => x.ObjectType != null);
```

Does anyone know why this would only cause a problem when Unit Testing?

Comment: Too old to ask probably. What is the type of `x.ObjectType`? `string`?